# SQL CONNECT ERROR: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Buenos días tengo un problema con el conector de mysql, el problema es el siguiente descargue una libreria en git [aca](https://github.com/doubaokun/MongoDB-to-MySQL) al colocar el comando  `node app.js import` me presenta el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
λ node app.js import
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
2 Jun 09:11:18 - Connect to MongoDB...
2 Jun 09:11:18 - Connect to MySQL...
2 Jun 09:11:18 - { Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:30:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:67:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:197:24)
    at Parser.write (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:62:12)
    at Protocol.write (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:37:16)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:110:26)
    at Protocol.handshake (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:42:41)
    at Connection.connect (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:81:18)
    at MySQL.getConnection (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\lib\mysql.js:36:15)
    at MySQL.create_table (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\lib\mysql.js:170:19)
    at new MySQL (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\lib\mysql.js:12:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\clonaciones\MongoDB-to-MySQL\app.js:12:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true }
2 Jun 09:11:18 - SQL CONNECT ERROR: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: No es cosa del conector sino de la password que se usa para acceder. Probablemente venga con una estandar y en mysql sea otra.

Comment: Actualice la libreria y ahora no me da el error pero al migrar la bd de mongo a mysql me da el siguiente error ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '4f3da288ae62b60e52000004' in 'field list'

Comment: Eso es cosa interna de la libreria. Si lo que quieres es pasar de MongoDB a MySQL hay mas opciones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855040/how-to-migrate-data-from-mongodb-to-mysql

Comment: @Lithorell estuve intentado ese paso segun con esto lo exporto a csv mongoexport --db periodico --collection usuarios --type=csv --fields correo,nombre,apellido,creado,status,titulo,bio,tipo --out /usuarios.csv
2017-06-02T11:03:26.804-0400    error parsing command line options: expected argument for flag `/o, /out', but got option `/usuarios.csv'  pero me da error 2017-06-02T11:03:26.829-0400    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information

Comment: Para iniciar sesión en MySql desde PhpMyAdmin se puede poner en usuario: root y en contraseña: una personalizada.